# How to use callback ref using ListView - ReactNative

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am having hard times trying to access ref from SectionHeader. I understand that I need to use ref as callback function instead of a string but I don't understand how to implement it.

```
render(){
    return (
      <ListView
        ref="mylist"
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={this.renderCampaign}
        style={styles.listView}
        renderSectionHeader={this.header.bind(this)}
        onChangeVisibleRows={this.updateFocus.bind(this)}/>
  );
 }
}

header(data){
    return(
     <MapView
      ref="mymap"
      style={styles.map}
      region={this.state.region}
      onRegionChange={this.onRegionChange.bind(this)}
      showsUserLocation={true}
     >
{this.state.markers.map(marker => (
   <MapView.Marker
     coordinate={marker.coordinate}
     title={marker.name}
     description={marker.reward_type}
   />
 ))}
   </MapView>
 );
}
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ref](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html) callback attribute of your listview would look like this

```
 <ListView
        ref={(comp) => this._mylist = comp}
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={this.renderCampaign}
        style={styles.listView}
        renderSectionHeader={this.header.bind(this)}
        onChangeVisibleRows={this.updateFocus.bind(this)}/>
```

Then you can access `this._mylist` without any problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and the quick reply :)